# Shopware 6 - How to debugging js file in adminstation

Tags: shopware

Right bow, after changing JS files, i must run the command `./bin/build-administration.sh administration:dev` to update js file on browser.

I am looking for a mode, where JS files will update directly after I reload the browser and don't need to run the command.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using the [Development template](https://github.com/shopware/development) you can use `./psh.phar administration:watch` to start the administration watch mode with hot-reloading. So your browser will automatically refresh the site after you made some changes to your administration files.

You can also get a full list of commands with`./psh.phar`.

If you're using the [production template](https://github.com/shopware/production) - *which i don't recommend for local plugin development* - you can use `bin/watch-administration.sh`. Those commmands are described within the **README** of the [production template repository](https://github.com/shopware/production).

Only after you finished all your work, you have to build the files for the production environment.

Take a look at this article to learn the difference between the production and development template: https://www.p16r.nl/2020-08-28-shopware-6-development-versus-production-template/